# Create document with pre-defined geo_shapes in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, gis

I have two indices:

1. Profiles - Has a field which is an array of `geo_shape`
2. Locations - Has a field geometry which is a `geo_shape`

Each document in profiles has many locations. Currently, a copy of locations' geometry is stored in profile documents.

Is it possible to improve this by creating a profile document with pre-defined `geo_shapes`? I've tried

```
PUT profiles/profile/1
{
  "locations": [
    {
      "indexed_shape": {
        "id": "LOC1",
        "index": "locations",
        "path": "geometry",
        "type": "location"
      }
    },
    {
      "indexed_shape": {
        "id": "LOC2",
        "index": "locations",
        "path": "geometry",
        "type": "location"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

which is much like the query syntax for pre-defined geo shapes, but to no avail. I can't find anything in the docs. Is there a solution to this problem, or do I have to manage copies?

Comment: The real question is what do you need to do with those locations stored in your profiles index?

Comment: @Val This is a simplified example, but I need to both search for profiles which have overlapping polygons (geo_shape really, could be geo collection) or contains a point.

I've thought about having a separate index called `profile_locations` which mirrors my Postgres table. Not sure if that makes more sense? Still, have the same problem with managing copies tho

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way (yet) to store references to indexed shapes. What you could do is to pre-index shapes into a dedicated index and then store the IDs of those shapes in the `locations` array in the `profiles` index. Then when you need to query, you can first do the query on the shapes index, gather the ids of the matching shapes and then query the profiles index using those ids. I don't see a way to make it shorter than that.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the suggestion, much appreciated!

Comment: @Val a quick question. What about when I want to search for profiles within a polygon and other criteria that lives on the profile? Is that somehow possible if I introduce a `profile_locations` index?

Comment: See my answer below ;-) You need to do your query in two steps, first figure out the shapes and then use that info in your second query with additional profile constraints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way (yet) to store references to indexed shapes. What you could do is to pre-index shapes into a dedicated index and then store the IDs of those shapes in the locations array in the profiles index, like this:

```
PUT shapes/doc/LOC1
{
  ... shape definition goes here ...
}
PUT shapes/doc/LOC2
{
  ... shape definition goes here ...
}

PUT profiles/doc/1
{
  "locations": [ "LOC1", "LOC2" ]
  ... other fields
}
```

Then, when you need to query, you can first do the query on the shapes index, gather the ids of the matching shapes and then query the profiles index using those ids. I don't see a way to make it shorter than that.

First, query the shapes and gather the ids:

```
POST shapes/_search?filter_path=hits.hits._id
{ 
  "query" : {
    "geo_shape": {
      "location": {
        "shape": {
          "type": "envelope",
          "coordinates" : [[13.0, 53.0], [14.0, 52.0]]
        },
        "relation": "within"
      }
    }
  }
}

=> returns "LOC1", "LOC3", "LOC4"
```

Finally, query the profiles index

```
POST profiles/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          ...other profile criteria go here...
        },
        { 
          "terms": {
            "locations": ["LOC1", "LOC3", "LOC4" ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```